# Convert String to Array to Objects in Observable

Tags: java, json, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to use a `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` to read from an endpoint, marshall the string to an Object (using javax.json) then convert an array on the object into it's individual components:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

client.start();

Observable<ObservableHttpResponse> observable = ObservableHttp.createRequest(HttpAsyncMethods.createGet(uri), client)
            .toObservable();

Observable<JsonArray> shareable = observable.flatMap(response -> response.getContent().map(bb -> {
        String stringVal = new String(bb);
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringVal);
        JsonObject jobj = Json.createReader(reader).readObject();
        return jobj.getJsonArray("elements");
    })).share();
```

I need to get the Json Array, then filter the objects of the array:

```
Observable<JsonObject> firstStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_1"));
Observable<JsonObject> secondStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_2"));
Observable<JsonObject> thirdStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_3"));
```

How do I convert the `Observable<JsonArray>` into a `ObservableJsonObject>`?

Because it's async, I can't use forEach to create some kind of array to buffer the data.

## UPDATE:

So Looking at using the CloseableHttpAsyncClient may not be the best solution for what I'm trying to achieve - I realised this morning (in the shower of all things) that I'm trying to process the data asynchronously to then make async calls.

Ideally, making the call to a CloseableHttpClient (sync) and passing the data to the Observable for filtering would be a more ideal approach (I don't need the first call to manage more than one http call).

```
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    } catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) { } catch(IOException ioe) {  }

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(result.toString());
    JsonObject jobj = Json.createReader(reader).readObject();
    JsonArray elements = jobj.getJsonArray("elements");

    List<JsonObject> objects = elements.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class);


    Observable<JsonObject> shareable = Observable.from(objects).share();

    Observable<JsonObject> firstStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_1"));
    Observable<JsonObject> secondStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_2"));
    Observable<JsonObject> thirdStream = shareable.filter(item -> item.getString("type").equals("TYPE_3"));


    firstStream.subscribe(record -> {
        //connect to SOTS/Facebook and store the results
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Json.createWriter(baos).writeObject(record);
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
    });

    secondStream.subscribe(record -> {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Json.createWriter(baos).writeObject(record);
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
    });

    thirdStream.subscribe(record -> {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Json.createWriter(baos).writeObject(record);
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    String myjson = "{\"elements\": [{\"text\":\"Obj1\"},{\"text\":\"Obj2\"}, {\"text\":\"Obj3\"}]}";

    Observable.just(myjson)
            .map(jsonStr -> new StringReader(myjson))
            .map(reader -> Json.createReader(reader).readObject())
            .map(jobj -> jobj.getJsonArray("elements"))
            .map(elements -> elements.toArray(new JsonObject[elements.size()]))
            .flatMap(jsonObjects -> Observable.from(jsonObjects))
            .subscribe(
                    (jsonObject) -> System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("text")),
                    throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace(),
                    () -> System.out.println("On complete"));
```

Result:

> 07-22 12:19:22.362    8032-8032/com.mediamanagment.app I/System.out﹕
>   Obj1
>  07-22 12:19:22.362    8032-8032/com.mediamanagment.app
>   I/System.out﹕ Obj2
>  07-22 12:19:22.362 8032-8032/com.mediamanagment.app I/System.out﹕ Obj3

**NOTE:**
You should use this dependency:

```
compile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
```

Instead this:

```
compile 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0'
```

If you will use `'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0'` you will get `javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found` at step:

```
.map(reader -> Json.createReader(reader).readObject())
```

Thereof, please, use `'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'`

**UPDATE:**
Also, instead of

```
.flatMap(jsonObjects -> Observable.from(jsonObjects))
```

You can use `flatMapIterable( )`:

```
.flatMapIterable(jsonObjects -> jsonObjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use another `flatMap()` call instead of the `map()` call you are using. Then use `Observable.create()` to emit `JsonObject`s

```
Observable<JsonObject> shareable =
        observable
                .flatMap(response -> response.getContent()
                        .flatMap(bb -> {
                            String stringVal = new String(bb);
                            StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringVal);
                            JsonObject jobj = Json.createReader(reader).readObject();
                            JsonArray elements = jobj.getJsonArray("elements");
                            return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                                for (int i = 0; i < elements.length(); i++) {
                                    subscriber.onNext(elements.getJSONObject(i));
                                }
                                subscriber.onCompleted();
                            });
                        }))
                .share();
```

Comment: You can get into trouble with this one because flatMap requires its inputs to  support backpressure and your Observable.create statement does not support backpressure. I'd suggest for that bit you use Observable.create(new AbstractOnSubscribe() {...}) which does offer backpressure support.

Comment: For the Observable.create you could also just build a list and return Observable.from(list).

Comment: So using the above solution, I ended up having to dematerialize the outcoming Observable (it returns Observerable<Observable<JsonObject>> so it'c close. But using dematerialize ends up return Observable<Object> (can't seem to work out how to parse the object back correctly)

Comment: if o is Observable<Observable<T>> then o.flatMap(x -> x) gives Observable<T>. flatten is the term used for this I think.